# How to pass column value as a function parameter ? SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm new here so go easy on me. How do I pass a column value as a function parameter?

I have this query to select months and years:

```
 SELECT 
     DATEPART(MONTH, a.RequestDate), 
     DATEPART(YEAR, a.RequestDate) 
 FROM 
     TABLE A
```

Sample data:

```
Months  Years 
------  -----
  5     2013
  3     2013
  1     2013
  9     2013
```

The values are not in order and could be duplicates.

I want to pass these value one by one to a function parameter automatically:

```
 SELECT WeekNo 
 FROM   _GLOBALDB.dbo.fn_WeekNoListInMonth(a.Months, a.Years)
```

The result would show what weeks would be in that particular month. For example:

```
 SELECT MIN(WeekNo) 
 FROM   fn_WeekNoListInMonth(5, 2013)
```

Expected result:

```
 WeekNO
 ------
   18
   19
   20
   21
```

I've tried this:

```
 SELECT MIN(WeekNo) 
 FROM fn_WeekNoListInMonth(A.Months, A.Years)
```

But it shows an error:

> The multi-part identifier "A.Months" could not be bound.
>   The multi-part identifier "t.Months" could not be bound.

Comment: So, you want to get all the output of `fn_WeekNoListInMonth()` for each row in `A`?  So, if there were 10 rows in A, you'd get between 40 and 50 rows back?  Or do you need to get the lowest value from the output of the function, for each row in 'A'?

Comment: @Ann L. All the output . if i want to get the lowest or the highest , i'll just add 'Min' for the lowest and 'max' for the highest , am i right ?

Comment: Pity you're on SQL 2005 -- this became a LOT easier with SQL 2008. I'm trying to remember what we used to do before that.

Comment: (Why was `MIN` in the question, if you weren't trying to get the top or bottom value?)

Comment: I get the impression that the result of this isn't going to be the final result. What is the information you're hoping to wind up with? Perhaps we can avoid doing this (as I remember it) unreasonably difficult thing.

Comment: (it's difficult because there is no easy way to "stack" the results of calls to table-valued functions into a single result set, in SQL Server 2005. You have to write loops (with or without cursors), call the function one time for each row you process, and stick the results in a temp table or table variable. It's UGLY.)

Comment: Whoops, I'm wrong. It came in 2005, as **Gordon Linoff** was kind enough to demonstrate.

Comment: I have a USP and table with weeks and years, i am trying to figure out a way to change the Last Week of every months into a 'String ' for example, week4=JanW4, week12=FebW4, week19=MarW4 . and i've gotten the function which gives me the list of week that is in that paticular months 'fn_WeekNoListInMonth(months, years)' but the months and years are taken from another table  that is why i needed an automatic way for the value of that months and years column to be pass to the function parameter automatically as this USP will be set to a schedule . Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Well, **Gordon Linoff** answered your original question, below. But, now that I know the context, I think you could probably do what you need to do with a subquery. I'll come back tomorrow (it's 10:13pm here) and supply an example.

Comment: Having thought this over, I think you need to ask another question, explaining the whole problem you want to solve (turning the last week of every month into a string) and what data you are starting with. I have some ideas of how to solve that, but if I post that question's answer to this question, I'd be breaking the rules.

Comment: **Gordon Linoff's** answer gives you the basics to solve the original problem: how to call a table-valued function once per row and combine all the results into one result set. If you need help refining his query into what you originally wanted, post a question about that.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use `cross apply` in SQL Server 2005:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM TABLE A CROSS APPLY
     dbo.fn_WeekNoListInMonth(month(a.RequestDate), year(a.RequestDate))
```

Comment: Yep, you're right. I remembered `CROSS APPLY` as coming in 2008 but I think that's because the employer I was working for skipped from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008.

Comment: the output is not what i want , it output random numbers and it output 2 column where as the fn_weekListInMonth function only output 1 column

Comment: @jonathan . . . This addresses what your question seems to be:  "I want to pass these value one by one to a function parameter automatically:".  If the rest of the query doesn't do what you want, then ask *another* question.

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte as ( 
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, RequestDate) as Months, DATEPART(YEAR, RequestDate) as Years
 FROM TABLE 
 )
SELECT WeekNO  FROM cte A 
CROSS APPLY dbo.fn_WeekNoListInMonth(month(A.Months, A.Years)
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors' question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.